# не могу текст из файла разделить символом - C#

Tags: c#, .net

Dotnet выдаёт ошибку: error CS0165: Использование локальной переменной "code", которой не присвоено значение.

код:

```
using System.IO;

ReadFile();

void ReadFile()
{
  String code;
  try
  {
    Console.Write("Enter txt-file path: ");
    string path = Console.ReadLine();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
    code = sr.ReadLine();
    while (code != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(code);
        code = sr.ReadLine();
      }
      sr.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Executing finally block.");
    }
    string code1 = code;
    string[] words = code1.Split('\n');
    Console.WriteLine(words[2]);
}
```

так уже пробовал:

```
using System.IO;

ReadFile();

void ReadFile()
{
  String code = "";
  try
  {
    Console.Write("Enter txt-file path: ");
    string path = Console.ReadLine();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
    code = sr.ReadLine();
    while (code != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(code);
        code = sr.ReadLine();
      }
      sr.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Executing finally block.");
    }
    string code1 = code;
    string[] words = code1.Split('\n');
    Console.WriteLine(words[2]);
}
```

Как можно исправить? Помогите!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Поместите ваш метод в какой то класс. Вызывайте его из другого метода. Объявляйте переменные там, где используете.

Comment: Во 2-м варианте что вам не нравиться? Ошибку, что вы указали быть ведь не должно. Это правда не пойму зачем вы делаете `string code1 = code;`...

Comment: Что этот код должен делать? Пока видно что он должен только неработать.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка [CS0165](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0165#example-2) появляется в том случе, когда значение переменной не было установлено (т.е где-то в блоке кода вы объявили переменную, но не присвоили ей значение).
Вы можете указывать поля внутри пространства класса (т.е вне метода `Main`, тогда компилятор ругаться не будет, однако исключение может появится на стадии работы программы, если вы конечно же не присвоите значние этому [полю](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields))

Например вот этот код не запустится

```
string a;
Console.WriteLine(a); //CS0165
```

Но если мы сделаем вот так, то код скомпилируется:

```
string a = "smth text";
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

---

Теперь к тому, что вы хотите сделать. Если Вам нужно прочитать файл и разбить его на строки, то можно сделать вот так (обратите внимание на [using](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)):

```
string path = Console.ReadLine();
List<string> list = new List<string>(); //если мы бы не написали new "List<string>()", то получили бы CS0165
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
{
    string fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
    list = fileContent.Split('\n').ToList();
}
```

Или вот так:

```
string path = Console.ReadLine();
string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(path);
string[] words = fileContent.Split('\n');
```

А можно и вообще ничего не сплитить, сразу получить массив строк из файла:

```
string path = Console.ReadLine();
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
```